# Probability densities on quotient spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, density-function, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ and $T$ be subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}^k$, respectively, where $d,k$ are positive integers. Endow them with their Borel $\sigma$ algebras, $\mathcal{B}_X$ and $\mathcal{B}_T$, respectively. Let $p(x;t)$ be the Lebesgue probability density associated to a Markov kernel $P(\cdot;\cdot)$ on $X\times T$: i.e.

1. for every fixed $B\in \mathcal{B}_X$, the map $t \mapsto P(B;t)$ is $\mathcal{B}_T$-measurable;
2. for every fixed $t \in T$, the map $B \mapsto P(B;t) $ is a probability measure on $(X,\mathcal{B}_X) $.

Thus, we could think of $p(x;t)$ as a conditional probability density.

Now, consider the quotient topological space $T^*$ where each two $t\in T$ and $t' \in T$ such that
$$
p(x;t)=p(x;t'), \quad \text{for almost every } x,
$$
are seen as the same element. Let $Q$ be a probability measure on $(T, \mathcal{B}_T)$, with Lebesgue density $q$, and let $\phi:T \mapsto T^*$ be the map associating to each $t\in T$ the corresponding representative in $T^*$; such a map may be not $1-\text{to}-1$.

**QUESTION** How does one obtain the probability density of $Q \circ \phi^{-1}$? Under which conditions  does such density exist? If it exists, how does it relate to $q$?

Comment: What's your reference measure on $T^*$ that you want a density with respect to? The push-forward of the Lesbegue measure under $\phi$?

Comment: Yes, the push-forward of the Lebesgue measure under $\phi$  could be a natural dominating measure to think of. I guess in that case we would have something like $Q \circ \phi^{-1}(B^*)=\int_{\phi^{-1}(B^*)} q(t) d\lambda(t)=\int_{B^*} q\circ \phi^{-1}(t^*) d \lambda \circ \phi^{-1}(t^*)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(T, \mathcal{B}_T)$ and $B^*$ is a Borel subset of $T^*$. Yet, as $\phi$ is not $1-\text{to}-1$, the expression $q\circ \phi^{-1}$ does not completely make sense to me, thus I'm not sure that the density on the quotient space might be given by such function.

Comment: If $\text{card}(\phi^{-1}(t^*))< \infty, \quad \forall t^* \in T^*$, do we rather have the identity $$ Q \circ \phi^{-1}(B^*)=\int_{\phi^{-1}(B^*)} q(t)d\lambda(t)=\int_{B^*} \text{card}(\phi^{-1}(t^*)) q(t^*) d\lambda\circ \phi^{-1}(t^*)$$? Would in this case the density be $\text{card}(\phi^{-1}(t^*)) q(t^*)$? What if however $\text{card}(\phi^{-1}(t^*)= \infty$ on a set of $t^*$  with non-null $\lambda \circ \phi^{-1}$-measure?